# Reducing the number of queries when selecting multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tags, subquery

**Goal:** Display multiple tags for each row (like the example shown below of stackoverflow)

**Details:** Every row is a result of a query from table '**news**' (query 1 below). Then, I am calling a second query from table '**tags**' (query 2 below).

**Queries:**

1. Query for selecting the news:

   `SELECT * FROM news`
2. Query for finding the tags - in a PHP **foreach statemnt**:

   `SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tags 
       INNER JOIN joiner j ON j.news_id = t.tag_id
       INNER JOIN news n ON n.news_id = j.news_id
   WHERE n.news_id = XXXXXXX`

The XXXXXX is the current news ID while being looped in PHP and this is the problem

**Question:**

1. If I am showing **10 news** articles, this results in **1 query** to get the news and **10 queries** to get the tags. Any better approach to handle showing **200 news per page**?
2. For CodeIgniter users, is there a simplified method to be used in the DB builder?

[image]

**Note:** Please comment if something needs to be elaborated more.

Comment: Instead of firing the query once per tags, you could grab all the `news_id`s first and then in the tags query do `WHERE n.news_id = XX OR n.news_id = XY OR n.news_id = YY`

Comment: You can use `WHERE n.news_id IN (X, Y, Z, ...)`. Also in your second query you are only using `news_id` from your news table in `WHERE` part. But that `news.news_id` is same as `joiner.news_id` so you can do `WHERE j.news_id IN (X, Y, Z, ...)` avoiding that extra join.

Comment: @mulquin I assume you mean once per 'news' and not 'tags'?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give this a try. However, if I understand correctly, I will have to query the DB to get the list of my news_id and then use that in both (news) and (tags) query.

Comment: You have to add `j.news_id` to `SELECT` part of second query.  You will load tags for all news selected by your first query in your second query. Then you will use some cycle to match the results of second query to their news.

Comment: Btw I don't know codeigniter but doesn't it have implemented some kind of active record design pattern with relation support? In Yii framework that i'm usually using all this is done by simply telling framework to use eager loading for that relation.

Comment: What's the problem? You already know how to JOIN, so just JOIN news !?!?!

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thank you again. I am not sure and I am new to it (I started last month) I tried to read a bit but I could not find something helpful and thus I decided to add the second part of the question for CodeIgniter users.

Comment: @Strawberry I understand your frustration when it seems easy to you but not much for a person like me who is not a programmer. I am trying to connect the dots and apply what as been suggested above

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of query...

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM news c
  JOIN joiner y
    ON y.news_id = c.news_id
  JOIN tags a
    ON a.tag_id = y.tag_id
```

Disclaimer: I am NOT a programmer

Comment: Problem with this query is, that it will select same news multiple time (for each assigned tag).

Comment: That's not a problem. That appears to be what you want!

Comment: It is a problem in fact. Why would you loop the same news twice? On the other hand, the tags can be several.